# Node Manager resources vs Scheduler Resources

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I was looking at default parameters for:

```
yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores = 8
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores = 32
```

For me this two parameters as default doesnt make any sense.

The first one say "the number of CPU cores that can be allocated for containers." (I imagine that is vcore)
The seconds says: "The maximum allocation for every container request at the RM". 
In my opinion, the second one must be equal or less than the first one.

How can allocate 32 vcores for a container if i have only 8 cores available per container?

Answer (score 1):

It is a documented issue: JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-3823